# mongoDB find all documnets in an array, but return only one per match

Tags: mongodb

I want to get ONE store location in each of the zip codes...

I have got as far as getting all the stores in the zip codes,

```
{ "address.zip": { $in: ['10003','10038','10121','12401'] } }
```

How would I only return ONE per zip?

It doesn't matter which ONE, just one - any ONE...
However IF I wanted to get back ONE specific one or ONE that had some attribute in the store object, how might I do that?

Structure:

```
{
    "store_name": "McPhersons",
    "address": {
        "street1": "23 N LA GRANGE RD",
        "city": "LA GRANGE",
        "state": "IL",
        "postal_code": "60525",
        "country": "USA"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell the structure of your collection?

Comment: see addition above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation query here. Something like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {$match: { "address.zip": { $in: ['10003','10038','10121','12401'] } }},
 {$group: {_id: "$address.zip", store_name: {$first: "$store_name"}, id: {$first: "$_id"}, address: {$first: "$address"}},
 {$project: {_id: "$id", store_name: "$store_name", address: "$address"}
]);
```

So in the above query, we are filtering using `$match`, then we are grouping using the `address.zip` and getting only the first match and then we are projecting the data according to the original collection.

Comment: very good - I tried group in aggregate in about  different variations, this looks like it might work - I'll get back shortly - thanks.

Comment: Worked great - Thanks!